# How to configure webSecurity for username and password with jwt?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to configure the server for authentication with username and password using JWT. I want to allow only the *sign-up* endpoint to be allowed publicly, the others requiring to be logged in. But apparently the sign-up endpoint still enters in the JWTAuthenticationFilter and returns 200 with no action done whatsoever.
For the rest of the endpoints it returns 403, when I would expect 401.
Below is the httpSecurity configuration:

```
private static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users/sign-up";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter** 
**JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter**

Edit: This is how my post request looks like:

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public ResponseEntity<AddUserResult> signUp(@RequestBody AddUserCommand command) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bus.executeCommand(command), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: Sign up URL when loads is it a get request?

Comment: It is a post request

Comment: did you try the solution that I posted

Comment: Ultimately I decided to go with basic authentication and https, so I stopped going any further with JWTs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the follwing , just mention the sign up or login URL that you want to be loaded without authentication . In this was you will be able to access the URL without any authentication.

Also in Controller method , it would be good If you do not mention @PreAuthorize annotation

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(userDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public User signup(@RequestBody @Valid SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        return userService.signup(signUpRequest)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "User Already Exists"));
    }
```